# How can I import a Mule connector in Anypoint Studio?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, mule4

So, I just downloaded an Azure Data Lake Storage connector from [here](https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/org.mule.modules/azure-storage-connector/) in the form of a jar file. How can I import that in Anypoint Studio?

Another option is to use the method defined [here](https://whishworks.github.io/azure-storage-connector/install-guide.html), which seems easier as we just need to provide a URL. But the URL is http://repository.mulesoft.org/connectors/releases/3.5.0. Would the connectors of this repository also work for Mulesoft 4+ or is there an other repository for that. If so, which is one is it?

Comment: You do not need to download it, on the same download page you can see ```Dependency Snippets```. Just paste that in your pom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second link is for Studio 6 which is for Mule 3 applications and connectors. It will not work for Studio 7 which is for Mule 4 applications. In Studio 7 connectors are not installed in the same sense as in Studio 6. They are just added to a Mule 4 application project.

There are two methods to use the connector. Add it to the project from Anypoint Exchange, by using the palette "Search in Exchange..." option, or just add the Maven coordinates as a dependency to the project's pom.xml. To get the Maven dependency from Exchange just go to the version list to the right and click in the 3 dots, dependency snippets. I don't recommend to try to use the JAR file directly because you might be missing additional dependencies.

Note that the connector may have licensing fees associated and not be free. You have to contact the provider for that. Contact information is available at the same Exchange page.